# How is the bonding in the [Au6C(PPh3)6]2+ cluster explained?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

How can carbon form six bonds in such a compound as $\ce{[Au6C(PPh3)6]^2+}?$ I understand how carbon with five bonds can be formed $(\ce{CH5+},$ for instance), but it shouldn't have enough electrons to form six bonds.

Comment: Carbon can well be hexacoordinate, or even hepta. This case isn't all that different from methanium you mention.

Comment: For example https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/51209/coordination-number-of-carbon-in-methyllithium-tetramer https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10415/hyperlithiated-carbon-species

Comment: Mildly related: I explain a (relatively simplistic) model of bonding for $\ce{SF6}$ in [Why do compounds like SF6 and SF4 exist but SH6 and SH4 don't?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/49844/16683). The discussion following the MO diagram briefly touches on species such as $\ce{CH6^2+}$. Now, if you treat $\ce{Au(PPh3)+}$ as a replacement for a single proton (the proper term is [isolobal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolobal_principle)), then that becomes $\ce{C[Au(PPh3)]6^2+}$. Note the qualitative similarity in the MO diagram there to the one andselisk has drawn.

Answer (score 13):

This is by no means a trivial case.
You are dealing with a so-called template or interstitial atom placement within a cluster shell.
There is a thorough review available [1, pp. 18–20] (reference numbers updated):

> An alternative way of satisfying the closed shell electronic requirements and retaining a positive charge on the cluster is possible if an interstitial atom is introduced.
>   For an octahedral gold cluster an additional gold atom is too large to satisfy the steric requirements of the interstitial cavity, but a small main group atom, e.g. C, N or O, is able to satisfy these steric requirements.
>   Figure 11 gives the relevant interaction diagram for octahedral $\ce{[Au6C(PPh3)6]^2+}$ and an interstitial carbon atom, which contributes just the right number of electrons to lead to a $\mathrm{[S^σ]^2[P^σ]^6}$ pseudo-spherical ground state conﬁguration.
>   It is noteworthy that this simple theoretical analysis was ﬁrst published in 1976 [[2](https://doi.org/10.1039/DT9760001163)], and the existence of $\ce{[Au6C(PPh3)6]^2+}$ was conﬁrmed by Schmidbaur and his coworkers in 1989 [3–5].
>   This compound had been isolated and structurally characterised previously, but the interstitial carbon had not been identiﬁed.
>   The introduction of the interstitial atom strengthens the radial interactions signiﬁcantly as a result of effective overlaps between the carbon $\mathrm{2s}$ and $\mathrm{2p}$ orbitals and the matching $\mathrm{S^σ}$ and $\mathrm{P^σ}$ cluster molecular orbitals.
>   In broad brush terms the stabilisation of the valence orbitals of the central atom are stabilised by $\mathrm{nβ^σ}$/degeneracy of the molecular orbitals.
>   If $\mathrm{β^σ(s)} = \mathrm{β^σ(p)} = \mathrm{β^σ(d)},$ the relative stabilisations are $\mathrm{6β^σ(s)},$ $\mathrm{2β^σ(p)},$ and $\mathrm{3β^σ(d)}.$
>   Therefore, the greatest stabilisation involves the $\mathrm{s}$ orbitals of the central
>   atom and increases as the number of metal atoms, $n,$ increases.
>   For filled shells the stabilisation energies are independent of geometry as long as the ligand polyhedron approximates to a sphere.
>   It follows that gold clusters with main group interstitial atoms are characterised by a pec of $12n + 8$ (sec 8) valence electrons, since each $\ce{AuPPh3}$ fragment is associated with a filled $\mathrm{d}$ shell containing $10$ electrons and a bonding $\ce{Au–P}$ bonding molecular orbital.
>
> [image: Molecular orbital interaction diagram for [Au6C(PPh3)6]^2+.]
>   **Fig. 11** Molecular orbital interaction diagram for $\ce{[Au6C(PPh3)6]^2+}.$
>   Similar analyses may be constructed for trigonal bipyramidal $\ce{[Au5N(PPh3)5]^2+}$ and tetrahedral $\ce{[Au4O(PPh3)4]^2+}$

#### References

1. *Gold Clusters, Colloids and Nanoparticles II*; Mingos, D. M. P., Ed.; Structure and Bonding; Springer International Publishing: Cham, **2014**; Vol. 162. DOI: [10.1007/978-3-319-07845-8](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-07845-8).
2. Mingos, D. M. P. Molecular-Orbital Calculations on Cluster Compounds of Gold. *J. Chem. Soc., Dalton Trans.* **1976**, No. 13, 1163–1169. DOI: [10.1039/DT9760001163](https://doi.org/10.1039/DT9760001163).
3. Schmidbaur, H., Grohmann, A., Olmos, M. E.; *Organogold chemistry*. In: Schmidbaur, H. (ed) *Gold progress in chemistry, biochemistry and technology*. Wiley, Chichester, **1999**. pp 648–731.
4. Steigelmann, O.; Bissinger, P.; Schmidbaur, H. Assembly of the $\ce{[CAu6]^{2⊕}}$ Cluster with a Tailor-Made Diphosphane Spanning the Octahedral Edges. *Angewandte Chemie International Edition in English* **1990**, 29 (12), 1399–1400. DOI: [10.1002/anie.199013991](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.199013991).
5. Schmidbaur, H.; Brachthäuser, B.; Steigelmann, O. Direct Observation of the Central Atom in $\ce{[C\{Au[(C6H5)2(PC6H4NMe2)]\}6](BF4)2}$ by $\ce{^{13}C}$ NMR Spectroscopy. *Angewandte Chemie International Edition in English* **1991**, 30 (11), 1488–1490. DOI: [10.1002/anie.199114881](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.199114881).

Comment: I wonder, if the LaTeX advanced editors use any handy reference generator, or if all is written down.. I bet for the former. When I was writing my diploma work, top tech were DOS based editors a latex was rubber.

Comment: @Poutnik I use [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) (desktop)/[Zbib](https://zbib.org/) (online) for references as there is no Bib(La)TeX support on any of the SE sites.

Comment: @Poutnik, the references in andselisk's answer are not in LaTeX (apart from the chemical formula in ref 5, which I assume is manually typed in). They are just plain Markdown. See https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4299/16683 for a tool which generates citations from a DOI.

Comment: @orthocresol I see. I had rather in mind perhaps just generated by LaTex aware word processing software, as I am not familiar with these systems. I will check the link, thanks.

Comment: You beat me to it, +1.  Compare with SF6 where the e_g orbitals are occupied.  As explained [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/121196/why-cant-o-form-of6?r=SearchResults) this orbital pair becomes antibonding if the central spacer atom is too small.  But if that level is empty, as in the gold cluster, you _want_ the small central atom to promote ligand-ligand bonding in the still occupied lower orbitals.